# css- swap order of 2 words

Tags: css, asp.net, html2canvas

I could really use some css help. Is it possible to swap the order of 2 words using css, WITHOUT using :after? (ex "Hello World" should become "World Hello")

The specific reason I cannot use :after which does in fact work, is that the div snapshot utility html2canvas.js does not take :before or :after into account, hence the workaround.

any help is very much appreciated.

Niko

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Can you include some code to give us some more context?

Comment: Can you put the words in different span tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stack the sentences with CSS z-index and using keyframes to make an effect of swapping. (see code-snippet).

After that you need to decide how/when to call for the change, through buttonclick or time. For calling you probably need some javascript.

If your are looking for a solution that really replaces the text in the HTML div, then you need solve that through javascript.

```css
.div-1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.div-2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  animation-name: swap;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 0;
}

@keyframes swap {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<div class="content">
    <div class="div-1">Hello World</div>
    <div class="div-2">World Hello</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for you help. I think i will look into JavaScript, because changing the text would be the better solution.